# jQuery Append and Delete Element with ajax Post Method

Tags: jquery, append

I want to add a div list element which include delete button and delete it after addition. When I try to delete that div element right after add that div, it deletes it from html but it is not deleted from server side. When I refresh page I see that element and I can delete it after refresh the page. My code is below. I use ajax.post method to send server and I use jquery post method to delete.

```
 $(function() {
    $("button#formDepartment").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addsomething.php",
            data: $('form#newDepartment').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("newDepartment").reset();
                idDep = data;

            },
            error: function(){
               alert("failure");
            }
        });

        var departmentName = $('#nameDepartment').val();

        var newDepartmentElem = 
            ' <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist"> \
            <div class="list-content"> \
              <span class="list-text">' + departmentName + '</span> \
              <div class="item-actions"> \
                <span class="btn btn-pure btn-icon" id="deleteDepartment" data-delete-id="' + idDep + '" ><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
          </div>';

        $(newDepartmentElem).hide().appendTo("#departmentList").slideDown('slow');

    });

    $(document).on('click', 'span#deleteDepartment', function() {
        var deleteId = $(this).data("delete-id");
        var removeItem = $(this).closest('.list-group-item');
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "this department will be deleted.",
            title: "Delete department",
            buttons: {
              success: {
                label: "Delete",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function() {
                    $.post("deletesomething.php",
                    {itemId : deleteId, deleteItem : "department"}
                    );
                    removeItem.slideUp(600);
                    toastr.error("Department deleted.");
                    console.log(deleteId);
                }
              },
              danger: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function() {
                }
              }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: check your backend code , the problem is there !!!

Comment: no it works. I can use it from other pages. I think I know where problem is but I don't know how I can fix. Maybe you can help. In my code I add new html div with mixed parameter , data-delete-id, because it can't find  data-id and can't send to server. to fix this I tried to dermine a global variable which includes id in ajax.post success callback function. But it doesn't work. I can not add the variable into my code. How can I create a global variable in success callback function?

Comment: when you insert , you return the 'id' somewhere ? or not  !

Comment: I updated my question. you can see idDep variable in ajax. success function. And I use it div element which I want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're sur that the returned id is the data it self  (`idDep = data;`) , all you have to do is putting all the code inside the ajax request , because outside the request as you did will set the `data-delete-id` fro the delete span to `undefined` (you can check by the browser inspector) , So , all you have to do is putting all the code inside success function as below :

```
$("button#formDepartment").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addsomething.php",
        data: $('form#newDepartment').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("newDepartment").reset();
            idDep = data;

            var departmentName = $('#nameDepartment').val();

            var newDepartmentElem = 
                ' <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist"> \
                <div class="list-content"> \
                  <span class="list-text">' + departmentName + '</span> \
                  <div class="item-actions"> \
                    <span class="btn btn-pure btn-icon" id="deleteDepartment" data-delete-id="' + idDep + '" ><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> \
                  </div> \
                </div> \
              </div>';

            $(newDepartmentElem).hide().appendTo("#departmentList").slideDown('slow');
        },
        error: function(){
           alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Actually first I did like that but when I put all code in ajax request, it takes a bit time to append div into dom. I thinks it must wait to server response. Can I do it in same time by clicking save button ?

Comment: Yes indeed it must wait untill the server response , you can improve this last by adding laoding icon when clicking button , and remove it in the ajax susccess function , for do the same in save button yes , also think to add laoding gif image or somethink like that :)